# Python Socket - Why connection closed after sending several messages?

Tags: python, sockets

I have a program that launches a TCP client as well as a server, and I can send messages and files from client to the server (they are all transferred in this direction). The server is expected to be always listening, and respond each upcoming message. But I found after I sent several messages, the server never responds again, unless I relaunch `connect` button on GUI.

here we have in the `server`,

```
# establish connection
def conn(self):
    self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.s.bind((self.ip, self.port))
    self.s.listen(1)
    print 'server ready.'
    self.conn, self.addr = self.s.accept()
    print 'Connected by', str(self.addr), '\n'

def recv(self):

    flag = self.conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    data = self.conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

    # this is a message
    if flag=='1':
        msg = "other >> %s" % data
        self.conn.send("success")
        print msg
        return

    # there will be a file  
    elif flag=='0':
        filename = data
        with open('new_'+filename, 'wb+') as f:
            while True:
               data = self.s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
               if not data: break # transfer finished
               f.write(data)
        size = os.path.getsize(filename)
        self.conn.send(str(size)) # echo size
        self.conn.send("success")
        return

# do not close connection unless exception raised
def run(self):
    self.conn()
    while True:
        try:
            # shoud I connect again each time here?
            self.recv()
        except:
            self.close()
            break
```

and in the `client` I have,

```
# expected to establish a connection
def conn(self):

    self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print 'client ready.'
    try:
        self.s.connect((self.ip, self.port))
        print 'connection established.'
    except:
        # close socket
        self.s.close()
        raise

def send(self, msg='', flag=1):

    if flag:
        self.s.send(str(flag))
        self.s.send(msg)
        sent = self.s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        print sent
    else:
        self.s.send(str(flag))
        self.s.send(msg) # send filename

        # send file in buffer-size
        with open(msg, 'rb') as f:
            while 1:
                data = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
                if not data: break
                self.s.send(data) # send block
        sent = self.s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        print 'sent: %s bytes' % sent
```

The problem is, should I put `client.socket.connect()` in each `send` function or I just leave it established and trust it would not down? And in the server, should I close connection after each message received? And why my connection is mysteriously down after a short time?

Another question is I noticed some code examples transfer files from server to client using `conn.send()`, instead, I sent files from client to server by `socket.send()`. Will this cause a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with function name which may cause your problem.

Change function name in your server code:

```
...
def connection(self):
...

...
def run(self):
    self.connection()
    while True:
...
```

Tell me if it works.

Comment: Now it seems to work. Thanks. So it would be garbage collected after a time, I guess?

Comment: @knh170 Yes, maybe, since it could be overwritten.

Comment: @knh170 : If you're still wondering what's going on, take a look at your original server code and tell us what `self.conn` refers to.